# Delete uploaded file if it is not moved to another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ashx

I am developing a commenting system with asp.net. A user can attach an image with "Attach" button and post the comment with "Post" button. Uploading the image starts when the user attaches it. An ASHX handler saves the uploaded file to "temp" folder. If the user clicks "Post" button, I move the image into a safe place. If he doesn't click "Post", closes the browser and goes away, the file remains in the "temp" folder. How can I delete a file from this "temp" folder one hour later after it is uploaded?

**Details:**
I thought using System.Timers.Timer in the ashx file used for uploading

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(300);
string fileName;

public void Cleaner()
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(300); //3 second
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Start();
}

protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs a)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Close();

    string path = "temp";
    string mapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../" + path);
    FileInfo TheFile = new FileInfo(mapPath + "\\" + fileName);
    if (TheFile.Exists) File.Delete(mapPath + "\\" + fileName);
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //Saving uploaded file
    Cleaner();
}
```

but I feel that I am not doing right.

Timer ticks after 3 seconds but HttpContext.Current in the timer_Elapsed() function returns null. Besides, file name also returns null after timer ticks. I couldn't find a way to pass file name as a parameter when binding an event. Simply, it is problematic. I am looking for a more elegant way to delete the uploaded file after one hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid timers as you will create one timer per file which will not scale very well at all.

How about this, run a clean up process on another thread in the web app started on app start that will delete temp files each time a session expires. That way you need no timers as the process will be prompted each time a session expires. You will need a class to store a reference (by unique name I guess) to the file which are still live (by that I mean the session to which they belong is still live) which the clean process can check.

LMK if you want some code pointers.

Comment: I looks good idea but I couldn't conceptualize yet. I don't know whether it is possible to get expiry time of the session.

Comment: Look in Global.asax, there is a handler that get called when a session expires.  In that handler you can get those files that were uploaded but not posted from the session and ask the clean up process to delete them.  Each time the cleanup process is asked to clean up files it should also look for orphaned files (those which have no session as these may not have been clean up due to app crash/restart).

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current should be null as the the context died **as soon as** response was sent.

If you were using unix, I would suggest write a script and run using cron. But seems you are using Windows.

So, write a program (exe) which deletes files (even better only image files) from temp directory based on creation date. Google and you will find lots of tutorial how to do it. Deleting a file is one line of code. If you are using system temp dir, that is another line of code. If you are using custom temp dir, you already know the path.
If you want to check creation time property (or last modified time property), you need to write few more lines.

Now, schedule the exe as per your requirement using windows task manager. Or you can use 3rd party task managers available for windows.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the session that uploaded the file may stil lbe live so the user may still want to post it.  Simply deleting the file because it is one hour old is flawed logic.

Comment: definition of *flawed* logic TOTALLY depends on business logic. I hope you understand. 1hr is not curved in stone, it is upto business logic.

Comment: I probably will not be authenticated to schedule a task in the machine I will use.

Comment: @ Sarwar Erfan, agreed.  but what ever logic you come up with will need to consider live sessions and thus would require interprocess communication.  Unless you set the lifetime very high, say 1 week, but that could be a problem if the site is high volume.